# PHP regular expression, remove specific attributes

Tags: php, regex

I have a simple URL:

> http://store.com/maison-entretien/aspirateur-nettoyeur/tous-les-aspirateurs-nettoyeurs.html?amp%3Butm_medium=push&%3Butm_source=application&p=2&price=12-260

I want to change the URL to be like this:

> http://store.com/maison-entretien/aspirateur-nettoyeur/tous-les-aspirateurs-nettoyeurs.html?p=2&price=12-260

I start resolving it with preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('/(&|\?)utm(.+)=[^&]*&/', '$1', preg_replace('/(&|\?)utm(.+)=[^&]*$/', '', $url2))
```

but I didn't get the result that I wanted.
I will happy if someone can help me and thank you

Comment: What result do you get from your code?

Comment: if you want, you can do it with `parse_url()` and `parse_str()`  without regex.

Answer (score 0):

I've made code for you with my logic. First, I separate the URL into two main URL and query using explode. Then in the query, I explode again to get the query need. After I get all of the requirement then I construct a new URL.

```
<?php

  $url     = "http://store.com/maison-entretien/aspirateur-nettoyeur/tous-les-aspirateurs-nettoyeurs.html?amp%3Butm_medium=push&%3Butm_source=application&p=2&price=12-260";
  $url     = explode("?",$url);
  $query   = explode("&",$url[1]);
  $newUrl  = $url[0]."?".$query[2]."&".$query[3];

  print_r($newUrl);
```